# Only 350 of 250k pages show strucutured data for organization/website in Google Search Console

Tags: seo, google-search-console, schema.org, structured-data

I am using **Organization/Website** schema across the app which is the same for every page.

We have around `250k` so there should be `250k` markups showing up.

[image: GWT report structured data]

**Note:** On testing with schema markup validator these come up completely as they should across all pages.

Surprisingly instead of rising up, these are getting down.

Any reason why is Google not picking up these?

Can duplication be an issue?

Comment: May be you are facing indexing problems. And How come it shows only 174 pages when you have 250K pages.

Comment: I wouldn't expect Google to pick up 250k duplicate items.  Why would you put the same schema on so many pages?

Comment: In my experience, what google reports it discovers can be even smaller that what is appearing under the rich results filer in search analytics. I dont hold much trust in that report.